# How to Hides the currently selected option from appearing when the drop down is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this option list but all i want to do is to be able to hide the selected option when the drop down is open, for example with the code below, i want the first option which is "Select an Option" to be hidden when the drop down is clicked.

```
<style>
#mainselection select {
   border: 0;
   color: #EEE;
   background: transparent;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 2px 10px;
   width: 378px;
   *width: 350px;
   *background: #58B14C;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#mainselection {
   overflow:hidden;
   width:350px;
   -moz-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
   border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 11px #330033;
   background: #58B14C url("http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png") no-repeat scroll 319px center;
}
</style>

<div id="mainselection">
  <select>
    <option>Select an Option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Did my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36680532/4763793) solve the problem? If it did not solve the issue please do add a comment below my answer so that I can modify my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").find('option:selected').hide();
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find('option').show().end().find('option:selected').hide();
  });
});
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").find('option:selected').hide();
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find('option').show().end().find('option:selected').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#mainselection select {
  border: 0;
  color: #EEE;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  width: 378px;
  *width: 350px;
  *background: #58B14C;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
#mainselection {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 350px;
  -moz-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
  border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 11px #330033;
  background: #58B14C url("http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png") no-repeat scroll 319px center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainselection">
  <select>
    <option>Select an Option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: tried using the code but that couldn't help, don't know if i did it right, please explain further, thanks.